# Difference between filter and reduce?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

What is the difference between ***filter()*** and ***reduce()*** methods on spark RDD ? In other words why ***filter()*** is transformation and ***reduce()*** is action ? To me both sounds similar.So what makes them different? is filter is narrow or wide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter is narrow as it only works on the per row level and returns another ( filtered ) rdd.
Reduce actually returns a single value that is computed going over the entire rdd. For this value to be returned an actual computation must occur which is why reduce is an action.

In general rdd.functions that have to return an actual value or write some output are actions while rdd.functions that return another rdd are transformations.

Only when an action is needed, the rdd transformations leading to it will take place ( Spark's laziness property )

Comment: it Makes sense  :)